# XElement.SetElementValue add new line before and after value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a code which replaces content of value tag in resx files. 
If I fetch value element and change its content everything works as expected:

```cs
foreach (XElement dataEl in doc.Root.Descendants("data"))
{
    XElement valueEl = dataEl.Element("value");
    valueEl.Value = valueEl.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(dataEl);
}
```

results in:

```xml
...
<value>myvalue</value>
...
```

But setting value with:

```cs
dataEl.SetElementValue("value", dataEl.Value);
```

results in:

```xml
...
<value>
myvalue
</value>
...
```

Why is `SetElementValue` adding these new lines?

Comment: why does it matter? :)

Comment: Because I lost 15 minutes with that and because I like to know how things work :-)

Comment: I know that feeling - perhaps the value itself contains "new line tags" 
try this: 
`dataEl.SetElementValue("value", dataEl.Value.Replace("\n",""));`

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this behaviour - both methods outputs the same result for `<root><data><value>myvalue</value></data></root>` - `<data>
  <value>myvalue</value>
</data>` (this is for .NET 4.0).

Comment: I uploaded one of resx files here: http://www.wikiupload.com/G5MV6T26NIJRIC4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XElement.Value from MSDN: Gets or sets the concatenated text contents of this element.

So dataEl.Value returns all text found inside of your "data" node. In this case only "value" child node exists so it returns its text, but in theory you could have other child nodes inside like "value2".

In that case you end up "myvalue" +newline+ "myvalue2" that seems the default implementation in .net, and i think it uses this newline if you have only one child also.

On the other hand: 
`XElement valueEl = dataEl.Element("value");`

valueEl don't have any child elements so valueEl.Value is only a string.

And why would you use dataEl.SetElementValue("value", dataEl.Value) ? Do you want to set  all concatenated text of the parent "data" node?

Comment: You are right, this was a stupid typo. It should have been: `dataEl.SetElementValue("value", valueEl.Value);`. Of course, this code won't do anything since I simplified it to point out the problem. Thanks.